# Bash [[ command not found

Tags: bash

soy nuevo en bash y por alguna razón en mi script no puedo realizar una comparación entre 2 cadenas. Dejo mi código:

```
#!bin/bash

A="word"

if [[ $A == "word" ]] ; then
    echo "yes"
    exit 0
fi
```

Estoy obteniendo la siguiente salida:

```
[[ word: command not found
```

He intentado diversas maneras. Lo ejecuto en terminal con:

```
bash script
```

Comment: ¿Has probado con poner `#!/bin/bash` como she-bang? Nota que te falta una `/` al comienzo.

Comment: Tu `script` funciona correctamente en mi terminal de linux: `GNU bash, versión 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`, incluso sin aplicar la corrección sugerida por @ManceRayder. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Trata de poner el encabezado como lo indican en los comentarios, pero se me hace extraño que no funcione incluso con `bash script`.
Algo que podrías hacer, para probar, es correr tu programa con `/bin/bash script`.

Supongo esto porque `bash` tiene el *built-in* `[[` que es una mejora o expansión de `[` o `test`. Y a veces lo que tu corres como `bash` no es el verdadero bash, sino un enlace simbólico a otro programa, a otro intérprete de comandos.

Para saber si de verdad estás corriendo `bash` cuando lo escribes, ejecuta esto en tu terminal.

```
$ readlink -f $(command -v "bash")
```

Eso podría aclarar si de verdad se está usando `/bin/bash` o , por ejemplo `/bin/dash` o `/bin/sh -> /bin/dash`, cuando escribes `bash script`.

De todas maneras, revisa con `ls -la /bin/bash` si se ve bien el programa, es decir, si no es un enlace a otro y modifica tu *shebang* para que apunte a la dirección correcta.

### Actualización.

Debido a que al parecer tu problema no era nada de esto y era lo que contestaste sobre un caracter no imprimible, me propuse tratar de replicar un caso similar.

Hago uso del caracter `<200c><200c>` después del token `]]` de tal que mi código queda de la siguiente manera, claro que uso `vim` y puedo ver esos caracteres no imprimibles.

```
#!/bin/bash

A="word"
if [[ $A == "word" ]] <200c><200c>
then
    echo "yes"
    exit 0
fi
```

Cuando trato de ver su contenido con `cat` sin parámetros, no puedo ver este caracter, y al ejecutarlo obtengo el siguiente error.

```
./invisible: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `‌‌'
./invisible: line 5: `if [[ $A == "word" ]] ‌‌'
```

Tal vez no es el mismo error pero creo que es un caso semejante. En tal caso se puede usar un parámetro de `cat` muy útil. Si se llega a tener la intuición de que todo se encuentra bien pero que hay un caracter extraño, el parámetro `-A` de `cat` es bastante útil el cual muestra finales de línea, tabs y caracteres no imprimibles de la forma `^` y `M-`.

Entonces, al usar `$ cat -A invisible` obtengo el siguiente resultado.

```
#!/bin/bash$
$
A="word"$
$
if [[ $A == "word" ]] M-bM-^@M-^LM-bM-^@M-^L$
then$
    echo "yes"$
    exit 0$
fi$
```

Y ahí es donde puedes ver, en `M-bM-^@M-^LM-bM-^@M-^L` ese caracter extraño.

Otras formas de ver eso es usando algún editor de terminal o con `od -cb` o `hd -c` o `hexdump -C`.

Answer (score 1):

Al ejecutar tu "script", produce un error:

```
`bash: ./script.sh: bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`
```

Esto es debido a que tienes mal escrito el encabezado "she-bang!":

```
`#!/bin/bash`
```

Luego de arreglar el encabezado, es ejecutado sin errores, aun asi, hay que hacer arreglos. Recuerda cuando vas a definir el parametro (variable):

```
`A="word"
      |  |
      v  v
if [[ "$A" == "word" ]]; then ...`
```

Siempre ponle citas o comillas,

Tambien recuerda ponerle un semicolon o punta y coma ";" al de;

```
`exit 0; <----`
```

Muchas veces, depende del sistema operativo (Ubuntu, Arch, Red Hat, etc..), te puede dar errores si no le pones el semicolo o punta y coma al final del comando y las citas o comillas al definir los variables.

Tu codigo debe leer asi:

```
`#!/bin/bash

A="word"

if [[ "$A" == "word" ]]; then
    echo "Yes"
    exit 0;
fi`
```

Para poder sacar los errores (debugging) que ocurren en el codigo, escribe esto:

`bash -x script.sh`

Si no quieres que el codigo completo se reprodusca en la pantalla y solamente quieres saber en donde es que ocurre el error, puedes hacer:

```
`A="word"
set -x
if [[ "$A" == "word" ]]; then
    echo "Yes"
    exit 0;
fi
set +x`
```

Asi, veras el lugar en donde ocurre el error.

Bueno, espero que esto te ayude.

Answer (score 0):

De hecho luego lo corregí y aún ocurría lo mismo. Lo extraño fué que lo pegué en un intérprete online de bash y tampoco funcionaba. Luego reescribí todo el código en el intérprete y sí funcionó. Pegué ambos códigos, el que tenía antes (copy paste) y el que había reescrito, eran idénticos sin embargo sólo funcionaba el último que reescribí (primero en la imágen).

Luego bastó con reescribir una línea de mi programa para que el problema se arreglara, al parecer se había colado algún carácter invisible como un espacio o algo que no logro entender que alteraba todo el funcionamiento en ejecución. Raro.

[image: Ejemplo]

El primero funcionaba, el segundo (copy paste) no. Ves alguna diferencia?

Extraño no? Muchas gracias.

Comment: El código debe ir como texto y no como imagen

Comment: eso hice arriba.

Comment: también si esto es una respuesta coloca el código aquí como texto y no como imagen